# when user deleted, delete user's token

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jwt

Imagine that there is one user which registered on our system and after a mean time user deleted from database by admin or me, etc but the user has a jwt token, this user can send requests to all services related to the USER role. What I want from you is implement a filter filtering such token which don't have real user in our system.

how ı can handle this problem ?

Comment: Without more details of your systems its difficult to say.  At first glance, even if a user has a JWT you probably still want to authenticate the user.  Other options include reducing the time a JWT is valid for, and using other means for authentication and JWT's for authorisations (Authentication and Authorisation being to separate concerns)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: guys, do you cannot see green tick ? the comment solved my problem already. so, what does your comment mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add validation token workflow before when the execute the code in the controller.

> REST (JWT) -> Validation Layser (jwt token expired || user not exist) -> Controller ( Process )

With each framework, we have a different to do that.
Sample Java Spring Boot
https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt

We can define

```java
class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter


...

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

So each request to our application it will go to the request filter and checking the token

Comment: should I create a method like isTokenHasUser to my JwtRequestFilter class ?

Comment: You can @UlaşMÜEZZİNOĞLU - you can query the database to check the user exist or not and return the 403 Forbidden